# What is an efficient way to manage an array of Javascript references (IJSObjectReference) in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, .net, blazor, interop

Consider a Javascript function like [`queryLocalFonts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/queryLocalFonts) (not mine so "don't use this, use Blazor" is not an option) that returns an array of objects, each could have a few properties as well as methods, making keeping a reference of them (`IJSObjectReference`) neccessary:

```js
class Foo {
    id = 1;
    name = "foo";
    
    doSomething1() { return "a"; }
    doSomething2() { return 1; }
}

function getAllFoos() {} // Return a Foo[]
```

From Blazor .NET code, I need to get all `Foo` instances, most of the time I only care about `id` and `name`. However sometimes I need a specific `Foo` instance and call their functions:

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime Js;
// ...
var foos = await Js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>();
```

I cannot keep it as `IJSObjectReference[]` or `IEnumerable<IJSObjectReference>`. Now iterating over `foos` is not simple. I have to write an interop method for each item. For example:

```js
getFooRef(arr, index) { return arr[index]; }
getFooName(arr, index) { return arr[index].name }
doSomething1ForFoo(arr, index) { return arr[index].doSomething1(); }
doSomething1ForFoos(arr) { /* ... */ }
```

And I am not the end user, I am writing a class library. To "safeguard" the reference, I could create classes like this:

```cs
    class FooCollection
    {
        readonly IJSObjectReference jsRef;
        readonly IJSRuntime js;
        internal FooCollection(IJSObjectReference jsRef, IJSRuntime js)
        {
            this.jsRef = jsRef;
            this.js = js;
        }

        public async Task<Foo> GetItem(int index)
        {
            var fooRef = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("getFooItem", this.jsRef, index);
            return new Foo(fooRef, js);
        }
    }

// I have to code Foo class similarly
```

IMO, this is not very nice as iterating the collection is not easy (not without one "round-trip" call for each item unless I write an interop JS method), a lot of code has to be written for `Foo` and `FooCollection`.

Is there a more clever way to manage this?

Comment: I don't know why you want to do that. You came to Blazor to avoid using Java Script, but you want to load a Java Script class in .NET and call its functions.

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh Some APIs are not available in Blazor. The above Foo class is just an example. Imagine you need Foo but it's only available through a Web APi for example

Comment: Are you sure your approach is the best approach? Have you considered JavaScript Isolation? Your examples paint a picture, but not the whole picture. Fair that some APIs aren't available in C#, but heavy reliance on JS could be detrimental to maintenance. JSInterop in my opinion should only be used for quick hit and run logic.

Comment: @Marius in my case, it's a Web API like [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API). Now I know someone already wrote a Blazor lib for it (which basically something like the above) but I want to improve it and also write a lib for another Web API as well. I don't see how JS Isolation helps in this case. Let's say I want to write a File System Access API RCL so other people can use it without worrying about writing interop. Is there any other approach?